# How to extract different attachment from Outlook email of different subject using Python?

Tags: python, automation, outlook, attachment

I am using this code to extract specific attachment files of a specific folder from outlook. But the problem is that I don't have a unique sender and I don't have a unique subject.
All what I know is that the subject could contain some specific words like (' report' , 'weekly report', 'technical report'...)
Here is my code, if you have any suggestion I would be grateful to you! Thanks :)

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
outlook = Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
root_folder = outlook.Folders.Item(1)
T1_folder=sub_folder.Folders['Folder1']
messages = T1_folder.Items

import os
outputDir = r"C:\Users\Desktop\Attachments"
i=0

for m in messages:
if m.Subject == 'Weekly Fleet Report': ### this part need to be changed
    body_content=m.Body
    for attachment in m.Attachments:
        i=i+1
        file=attachment.SaveAsFile(os.path.join(outputDir,attachment.FileName+str(i)+'.xlsx'))
```

Comment: So the subject needs to contain the word "report"? How about `if 'report' in m.Subject.lower():`

Comment: Thank you so much!!! this is exactly what I am looking for!! Many thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

```
# creating a tuple of possible subjects
subjects = (' report' , 'weekly report', 'technical report')

for m in messages:
    # check if any of the keywords are present in email subject
    if any(subject in m.subject for subject in subjects):
        body_content=m.Body
        for attachment in m.Attachments:
            i=i+1
            file=attachment.SaveAsFile(os.path.join(outputDir,attachment.FileName+str(i)+'.xlsx'))
```